# Error: Type 'ui.Window' not found. ui.Window get window => ui.window;

Tags: flutter

I dont know why i keep getting this error at times. Can causes this error.
thanks in advance : )

```
/G:/ssd%20backup/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/binding.dart:88:3: Error: Type 
'ui.Window' not found.
 ui.Window get window => ui.window;
 ^^^^^^^^^
 /G:/ssd%20backup/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:60:14: Error: Type 'ui.Window' 
 not found.
 required ui.Window window,
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I used `TextField()` in a `CupertinoApp()` 
Instead use `CupertinoTextField()`